Restrict keybinding for git.stageAll in VSC
I have these keybinds in my keybindings.json:
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+up",
    "command": "git.stageAll",
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+down",
    "command": "git.unstageAll",
  }

They work, but I want to restrict them, so that they may only be activated when the git source control menu is selected (opened with ctrl + shift + g for me).
I saw a version for this here, but I'm still allowed to stage/unstage changes without selecting the source menu first when using this restriction: "workbench.scm.active".
What is the proper when to use for this restriction?

use ctrl+shift+g as a prefix
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+g space",
    "command": "open_menu_command",
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+g ctrl+shift+up",
    "command": "git.stageAll",
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+g ctrl+shift+down",
    "command": "git.unstageAll",
  }

fill in the open_menu_command with the original ctrl+shift+g command.
If you want to do it with a when you have to dump the context to the developer console and try to find a key that is marking that situation.

Is open_menu_command necessary? It seems to work without it.

Never mind, I can't get it to open up the menu using this setup. It also says the command open_menu_command isn't found.

@Pompan you said you had a command bound to ctrl+shift+g to open the menu, use that instead of open_menu_command
